# Defeating the False King (Demon's Souls)

Tags: demons-souls

I'm having some difficulty defeating the False King boss (1-4). Would anyone like to share their tips?

I've tried:

- Fire Spray roasting
- Physical Melee (Sharp Winged Spear +5 and Purple Flame Shield +9)
- Physical/Magic Melee (Crescent Falchion +4 and PFS +9)

I've also tried using Firestorm, but I need to try this again properly.

It is possible to bow him initally from the entrance, but he incrementally moves away until the shots are barely effective (and my character does not have high Dexterity).

Are his ranged attacks magic-based? (Should I be using the Dark Silver Shield?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since asking this question I managed to beat him. This is how I did it:

**My equipment:**

- **Left Hand:** Purple Flame Shield +9, Talisman of Beasts
- **Right Hand:** Crescent Falchion +4, Sticky Compound Short Bow +5 (normal arrows)
- **Magic:** Warding

I think any decent sword/shield combo would work, as would a Catalyst instead of the Talisman. Any bow would be fine.

**Basic tactics:**

- Have the shield and sword combination selected most of the time.
- Be prepared to quickly switch to bow and fire off a shot (or use a throwing weapon)
- Cast Warding before engaging. Recast when the opportunity arises.
- Have healing items in your quick-access slot. Heal when the opportunity arise.
- Be patient and don't push your luck with too many successive hits.
- Keep your stamina up by lowering your sheild when possible.
- Stay away from him whenever possible.

I've found the opportunity for healing/recasting of Warding to be just after the False King has performed his final successive shockwave move, as long as you are not within sword-striking range.

**Attack Types:**

The False King has a few different types of attacks:

- AoE explosion spell
- Charge and swipe
- Multiple swipe with shockwave
- Soulsucker (steals one of your Soul Levels)

*AoE explosion spell*

Don't try to outrun or block this. Instead switch to the bow and shoot him, interrupting the spell. The spell charge time is long enough to allow this. A thrown weapon would probably work just as well.

*Charge and swipe*

Roll out of the way, turn and hit him 1 or 2 times, then back away. This is the only safe time to attack via sword.

*Multiple swipe with shockwave*

If you're close, block his hits with your shield and roll/move away as soon as possible.
If you're further away, move sideways to avoid the shockwave, or block it with your shield.

*Soulsucker*

If his hand is glowing bright white, he is preparing the Soulsucker move. Roll away as fast as possible.

Keep this up and the False King will be yet another Demon's Soul in your cap.

Comment: I feel a bit silly answering my own question, but there was nothing forthcoming from the rest of Gaming.SE. Hasn't anyone completed Demon's Souls yet??

Comment: The question only just appeared on my home page as a result of your answer. I would have been able to help otherwise.

Comment: @qpingu: Your answer may help someone else, so please post it anyway. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I used a Crescent Falchion, and magic regen ring, fairly light armor, Dark Heater Shield +4, and  Warding and Soul Ray (also had heal and Evacuate, but I did a kind of wonky magic+miracles build). I did my best to keep him at a distance. I especially noticed that he likes to do the big explosion thing 2-3 times in a row, it takes him a minute to charge and it's interruptible. So I mostly ran and dodged until he started powering up for it, and then I shot him with a Soul Ray, then used a spice/grass if need be or shot him again if not (assuming he started charging again). Recast warding as needed but mostly just was careful to avoid his attacks as my magic/health slowly regened due to my gear.